# Tokenize concatenated characters based on given dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to tokenize concatenated characters based on the given dictionary and give and output of tokenized words found. For example, I have the following

```
dictionary = ['yak', 'kin', 'yakkin', 'khai', 'koo']
chars = 'yakkinpadthaikhaikoo'
```

Output should be something like the following:

```
[('yakkin', (0, 6), 6), ('padthai', (6, 13), 7), ('khai', (13, 17), 4), ('koo', (17, 20), 3)]
```

I would like to get the **list of tuple** as an output. The first element in tuple is the word found in dictionary, second element is character offset and third element is length of the word found. If characters is not found, we'll chunk them together into one word e.g. `padthai` in above case. If multiple words found from the dictionary, we'll select the longest one (select `yakkin` instead of `yak` and `kin`).

I have my current implementation below. It starts with index if 0 then looping through characters (it doesn't work yet).

```
import numpy as np

def tokenize(chars, dictionary):
    n_chars = len(chars)
    start = 0
    char_found = []
    words = []
    for _ in range(int(n_chars/3)):
        for r in range(1, n_chars + 1):
            if chars[start:(start + r)] in dictionary:
                char_found.append((chars[start:(start + r)], (start, start + r), len(chars[start:start+r])))
        id_offset = np.argmax([t[1][1] for t in char_found])
        start = char_found[id_offset][2]
        if char_found[id_offset] not in words:
            words.append(char_found[id_offset])
    return words

tokenize(chars, dictionary) # give only [('yakkin', (0, 6), 6)]
```

I have hard time wrap around my head to solve this problem. Please feels free to comment/suggest!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got `('padthai', (6, 13), 7)`?

Comment: Basically, I would like to starts from character 6 til end of characters. If I cannot find any words that match my dictionary, I will move to character 7 and so on. When I reach character 13, I should find the new word when searching til the end. I can therefore chunking character `6:13` together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can look a bit nasty, but it works

```
def tokenize(string, dictionary):
    # sorting dictionary words by length
    # because we need to find longest word if its possible
    # like "yakkin" instead of "yak"
    sorted_dictionary = sorted(dictionary,
                               key=lambda word: len(word),
                               reverse=True)
    start = 0
    tokens = []
    while start < len(string):
        substring = string[start:]
        try:
            word = next(word
                        for word in sorted_dictionary
                        if substring.startswith(word))
            offset = len(word)
        except StopIteration:
            # no words from dictionary were found
            # at the beginning of substring,
            # looking for next appearance of dictionary words
            words_indexes = [substring.find(word)
                             for word in sorted_dictionary]
            # if word is not found, "str.find" method returns -1
            appeared_words_indexes = filter(lambda index: index > 0,
                                            words_indexes)
            try:
                offset = min(appeared_words_indexes)
            except ValueError:
                # an empty sequence was passed to "min" function
                # because there are no words from dictionary in substring
                offset = len(substring)
            word = substring[:offset]
        token = word, (start, start + offset), offset
        tokens.append(token)
        start += offset
    return tokens
```

gives output

```
>>>tokenize('yakkinpadthaikhaikoo', dictionary)
[('yakkin', (0, 6), 6), 
 ('padthai', (6, 13), 7), 
 ('khai', (13, 17), 4), 
 ('koo', (17, 20), 3)]
>>>tokenize('lolyakhaiyakkinpadthaikhaikoolol', dictionary)
[('lol', (0, 3), 3), 
 ('yak', (3, 6), 3), 
 ('hai', (6, 9), 3), 
 ('yakkin', (9, 15), 6), 
 ('padthai', (15, 22), 7), 
 ('khai', (22, 26), 4), 
 ('koo', (26, 29), 3), 
 ('lol', (29, 32), 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find() to find the starting index of the word, and the length of the word is known thanks to len(). Iterate through each word in the dictionary, and your list is complete!

```
def tokenize(chars, word_list):
    tokens = []
    for word in word_list:
        word_len = len(word)
        index = 0

        # skips words that appear in longer words
        skip = False
        for other_word in word_list:
            if word in other_word and len(other_word) > len(word):
                print("skipped word:", word)
                skip = True
        if skip:
            continue

        while index < len(chars):
            index = chars.find(word, index) # start search from index
            if index == -1: # find() returns -1 if not found
                break
            # Append the tuple and continue the search at the end of the word
            tokens.append((word, (index, word_len+index), word_len))
            index += word_len

    return tokens
```

Then we can run it for the following output:

```
>>>tokenize('yakkinpadthaikhaikoo', ['yak', 'kin', 'yakkin', 'khai', 'koo'])

skipped word: yak
skipped word: kin
[('yakkin', (0, 6), 6), 
 ('khai', (13, 17), 4), 
 ('koo', (17, 20), 3)]
```

Comment: This is almost like the format what I want but you have to remove `yak` and `kin` in this case too cause we'll select `yakkin` instead. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sure thing, see the edits I made. I just added another iterative loop that checks if a word is found in a longer word. Just a heads up, this method is case sensitive, though you can use ``lower()`` or ``upper()`` to ignore case.